# How are SPICE files created compared to S4P files generated from a VNA?

Tags: ltspice, common-mode, s-parameters, common-mode-choke, ti-ccstudio

When measuring impedance versus frequency using the same data in both SPICE and S4P formats, why do I obtain different results?

**COMMON MODE IMPEDANCE**
[image: How are SPICE files created compared to S4P files generated from a VNA?][image: Spice file from TDK]
Common mode impedance 10514 Ohm at 79.1 MHz
[image: S4P File of TDK]
S4P FILE FOR THE SAME CMC
[image: Zcommon]

Common mode impedance 10171 Ohm at 26 MHz

[TDK ACT1210G-800](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/list#part_no=ACT1210G-800-2P-TL05&site=FBNXDO0R&charset=UTF-8&group=tdk_pdc_en&design=producttdkcom-en&fromsyncsearch=1&_l=20&_p=1&_c=part_no-part_no&_d=0)